# Exclude Less Directory

Tags: gruntjs

I am using [gruntjs](/questions/tagged/gruntjs) to build my src and I want to exclude `css/less/*.less` from my published folder.

Should I be using the *exclude list* or is this an issue with the copy task?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `.buildignore` file and add css/less